# Неверные хеши файлов

Tags: linux, windows, boot, железо

Вчера в моём компьютере что-то умерло окончательно, хотя и ранее такое наблюдалось последние полгода.Последнее время мой ПК выдавал неверные хеши для скаченных файлов. Что проявлялось при скачивании образов linux-дистров и а так же при netinstall, windows же молча глючит. Попытки повторить все действийя на других машинах были удачными.И вот свершилось. Первый день - `CMOS checksum error`, второй день - отказ запуска ОС и отказ установки новой (образ которой был скачан и записан другой машиной) ОС.Вот теперь интересно что лечить,откуда начинать?

Comment: memtest.. что-то популярная нынче тулза ))

Comment: батарейку сменил, проблема таже. Тест оперативы заставил освободить один слот, как оказалось он работет через раз. Систему установить так и не удалось.Видимо дело в материнке и не только слот в ней перестал работать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема либо в линейках памяти, либо в северном мосте (контроллер управления памятью) на материнской плате.

Что можно сделать:

1. Полностью отключите питание компьютера (выдерните кабель), после подождите секунд 20-30.
2. Выньте линейки памяти.
3. Протрите контакты линеек ластиком (или стёркой, как это в некоторых городах называют), желательно жёстким, но очень аккуратно, чтобы микросхемы не задеть!
4. Вставьте обратно, и запустите комп.

Если всё заработало - то это значит, что у линеек памяти окислились контакты, а вы их очистили.

Если всё же не работает, то попробуйте поочерёдно поубирать линейки памяти, сохраняя соответствие возможностям материнки (в мануале на материнку это есть).

Если и после манипуляций с планками памяти ничего не помогает - то это проблемы северного моста, а значит нужно менять материнку.

Пытался пояснить предельно ясно. Сам так делал - всё проверено.